# crontab command is not executed

Tags: bash, cron

I am new to bash scripting and all.

I am having the following use case.

I have a simple bash file which should execute every 5 min.

I have an AWS-ec2-instance where i copied this file and provided the following configuration in `crontab` of ec2-instance:

```
#SHELL=/bin/bash
#PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#MAILTO=root

*/1  *  *  *  * /bin/bash  /home/ec2-user/info.sh
```

unfortunately the `crontab` is not getting executed, when I run the bash script manually then it is working.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean configuration in `crontab` as in `/etc/crontab` file, you should add the executor user before the command `/bin/bash /home/ec2-user/info.sh`.

See also: Two Other Types of [Crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

> m h dom mon dow user command